# Monitoring scripts and sending email when it crashes

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, crash, monitoring

I have some perl scripts which are scheduled using task scheduler in windows 2003 R2 and 2008. These scripts are called directly using perl.exe or via a batch file.

Sometimes these scripts fails to execute (crashes maybe) and we are not aware of these crashes.

Are there any ways a mail can be sent when these script crashes? more or less like monitoring of these scripts

Thanks in advance

Karthik

Answer (score 1):

Why monitor the scripts from the outside when you can make the plugins to monitor theirself? First you can use **eval** in order to catch errors, and if an error occours you can send an email with the **Net::SMTP module** as rpg suggested. However I highly recommend you to use some kind of log file in order to keep trace of what happened right before the error and what caused the error. Your main goal should be to avoid the error. That ofcourse requires you to modify the scripts, if, for any reason, you cannot do that then the situation may be a little more complicated because you need another script.

With the [Win32::Process::Info](http://search.cpan.org/~wyant/Win32-Process-Info-1.018/lib/Win32/Process/Info.pm) module you can retrieve running processes on Windows and check if your plugin is running or not.

```
while(1) {
    my $found = false;
    my $p = Win32::Process::Info->new;
    foreach my $proc ($pi->GetProcInfo) {
        if ($proc->{Name} =~ /yourscriptname/i ) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if ($found eq 'false') {
        # send email
        my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new("yoursmtpserver");
        eval {
            $smtp->mail("sender@test.it");
            $smtp->recipient("recipient@test.it");
            $smtp->data;
            $smtp->datasend("From: sender@test.it");
            $smtp->datasend("\n");
            $smtp->datasend("To: recipient@test.it");
            $smtp->datasend("\n");
            $smtp->datasend("Subject: Plugin crashed!");
            $smtp->datasend("\n");
            $smtp->datasend("Plugin crashed!");
            $smtp->dataend;
            $smtp->quit;
        };
    }
    sleep(300);
}
```

I did not test this code because I don't have Perl installed on Windows but the logic should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

For monitoring - Please check the error code. This will help you for its failure.

For mail sending - You can use Net::SMTP module to send email. Let me know if you need a code snippet for it.

Comment: what if the Perl file itself crashes in case of not being called directly and not via batch files

Answer (score 0):

You can use PushMon to monitor your scripts. What you do is create PushMon URLs that matches the schedule of your Perl scripts. Then you should "ping" these URLs when your scripts run successfully. If these URLs are not accessed, maybe because your scripts crashed or there's a power failure, PushMon will notify you by email.

Disclaimer: I am associated with PushMon.

Comment: I am looking for servers within intranet

Comment: Ah yes, this is cloud based. I'll let you know if I see something that can be installed in-house. One thing with setting this up within the intranet is you have to monitor power outages and SMTP issues.